# compatible dll file for ionic.zip.dll

Tags: cocoa

i have an application in MS Visual studio that uses ionic.zip.dll, can any one knows the compatible dll for the same in Mac OS X so that the file zipped in Mac OS X application could be opened with the same ionic.zip.dll.

Comment: Ya that i know but i want any framework which does the same function as ionic.zip.dll for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about ionic.zip.dll but if you want to zip/unzip files in Cocoa you could try this [Google framework](http://code.google.com/p/zip-framework/).